# Is there a more pythonic way to write the code below without changing much of it

Tags: python, dictionary

```
input_list = [["nut", "bolt", "screw"], [1,5,6],[2,3,1],[78,90,1]]
def basichandler():
    file_dict = dict()
    for data in input_list:
        for element in data:
            keys = input_list[0]
            values = input_list[1:]
            for key in keys:
            file_dict[key] = values[0][0], values[1][0], values[2][0]
            new_values = values[0][1],values[1][1],values[2][1]
            new_keys = keys[1:]
                for key in new_keys:
                    file_dict[key] = new_values
                    next_new_values = values[0][2],values[1][2],values[2][2]
                    next_new_keys = keys[2:]
                    for key in next_new_keys:
                        file_dict[key] = next_new_values
     return file_dict
```

output:

```
{'nut': (1, 2, 78), 'bolt': (5, 3, 90), 'screw': (6, 1, 1)}
```

How can i get the same result but make my code more dynamic, i am using new_values and next_new_values and i am getting those values by indexing it, its possible in this case as i do not have a long nested list, but if i had a long list it would be cumbersome and almost impossible. How can i make it more pythonic so that it could handle any amount of nested list?

Comment: It's not clear what a more complex input would look like. However, you can implement your current approach much more simply with `zip`: `keys = input_list[0]; values = zip(*input_list[1:]); file_dict = dict(zip(keys, values))`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`zip` lets you "transpose" sequences; it seems to be exactly what you need:

```
keys = input_list[0]            # produces ["nut", "bolt", "screw"]
values = zip(*input_list[1:])   # produces [[1,2,78], [5,3,90], [6,1,1]]
file_dict = dict(zip(keys, values)) # pairs up each key with the corresponding value
return file_dict
```

Answer (score 1):

A solution with [extended tuple unpacking](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-3132/):

```py
>>> {key: vals for (key, *vals) in zip(*input_list)}
{'nut': [1, 2, 78], 'bolt': [5, 3, 90], 'screw': [6, 1, 1]}
```

Comment: Nice answer, but the parentheses can be omitted `... for key, *vals ...`.

Comment: Yes they can, but I prefer to have them for readability. I guess it's a matter of taste.